# When does jQuery mobile read the hash?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

If you have a URL with a hash, for example:

> www.my_jqm_site.com/#some_page_request

... at what point during the jqm page event sequence does jqm read the hash?

```
Event sequence when navigating from jqm_page_A to jqm_page_B ... thanks Muhammed Basil.

  - document --- script time (js is readable, but DOM is not ready yet)
  - document --- ready
  - page B   --- pagebeforecreate
  - page B   --- pagecreate
  - page B   --- pageinit
  - page A   --- pagebeforehide
  - page B   --- pagebeforeshow
  - page A   --- pageremove
  - page A   --- pagehide
  - page B   --- pageshow
  - body     --- onLoad
```

---

**EDIT**: if I change the hash at script time:

```
<script>
  window.location.hash = "#some_other_page_request" 
</script>
```

it will override the incoming hash, '#some_page_request', and thus jqm will navigate to  instead.

This suggests that jqm reads the hash at-or-after script-time (ie. at, or after, $(document).ready(...)).

Comment: did you try looking at the unminified version of jquery mobile and searching for each of the functions you named, and then the word `hash`?

Answer (score 1):

During the **pagebeforehide** event.

This is the first element to be dispatched during the transition prom page A to page B.

> Description: Triggered on the "fromPage" we are transitioning away from, before the actual transition animation is kicked off.

This is the first page to receive data object as their 2nd arg. This data object has the object that contains the page DOM element that we are transitioning to.

Official documentation: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforehide/

All events before it are events common to page creation and they will also trigger during the initial app loading when first page is about to be shown:

```
- page B   ---pagebeforecreate
- page B   ---pagecreate
- page B   ---pageinit
```

During those 3 events system don't have knowledge is this a app loading or page transition. They are here just to create a new page.

Comment: but if you are directly accessing the url: www.my_jqm_site.com/#some_page_request, then no pagebeforehide  will be triggered

Comment: Then this is something competently different. In this case none of them are use to read #. It is triggered during the framework initialization.

Comment: One more thing, If you want to know when page is initialized through the # then you cant use page events. Page events will occur after the page has been selected for initialization. My main answer will told you only when pages will start transition from one page to another.

Comment: actually this might be the answer: "after the page has been **SELECTED** for initialization" ... so somewhere in the jqm there is a onPageSelectForInitialView ... and, yes, I guess you are right in that it has to precede the other standard page events (makes sense)

Comment: Can you tell me what do you want to do? maybe I can help.

Comment: I am wanting to use GET vars appended to my url (?...=...&...=...). There will be times when there are ONLY these GET vars appended, but other time when there are both GETs and jqm's hash. ...... My GET vars will include an initial_page_view instruction, which could conflict with jqm's hash initial_page_view instruction. Imagine this: 'www.myy_jqm_site.com/?first=page_G#page_H'. if I use `j(documnet).ready(f(){location.href = '<?php echo $_GET[ 'first' ] ?>'})`, that seems to override the jqm hash request ... I guess that suggests that doc.ready occurs BEFORE jqm reads hash.